How to make an implicit expression in the output become explicit?
I am solving a cubic equation. For a general form, i.e.,
$$a x^3+b x^2+ c x +d=0$$
by the code

    Sol2 = Solve[a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d == 0, x] // FullSimplify


I get the solution without implicit expressions,

    {{x -> -(b/(
         3 a)) - (2^(
           1/3) (-b^2 + 3 a c))/(3 a (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + 
             Sqrt[-4 (b^2 - 3 a c)^3 + (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)^2])^(
           1/3)) + (1/(
        3 2^(1/3)
          a))((-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + 
          Sqrt[-4 (b^2 - 3 a c)^3 + (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)^2])^(
        1/3))}, {x -> -(b/(
         3 a)) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-b^2 + 3 a c))/(3 2^(2/3)
            a (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + 
             Sqrt[-4 (b^2 - 3 a c)^3 + (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)^2])^(
           1/3)) - (1/(
        6 2^(1/3)
          a))(1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + 
           Sqrt[-4 (b^2 - 3 a c)^3 + (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)^2])^(
         1/3)}, {x -> -(b/(
         3 a)) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-b^2 + 3 a c))/(3 2^(2/3)
            a (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + 
             Sqrt[-4 (b^2 - 3 a c)^3 + (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)^2])^(
           1/3)) - 1/(
         6 2^(1/3)
           a) (1 + I Sqrt[3])  (-2 b^3 + 9 a b c - 27 a^2 d + 
           Sqrt[-4 (b^2 - 3 a c)^3 + (2 b^3 - 9 a b c + 27 a^2 d)^2])^(
         1/3)}


However, for a reduced equation, where $a=1$ and $c=0$, by the code

    Sol = Solve[x^3 + b*x^2 + d == 0, x] // FullSimplify


I get a solution

    {{x -> 1/
        3 ((-b^3 + 3/2 (-9 d + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[d (4 b^3 + 27 d)]))^(1/3) + 
          b (-1 + b/(-b^3 + 3/2 (-9 d + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[d (4 b^3 + 27 d)]))^(
             1/3)))}, {x -> 
       1/6 (-2 b - (
          2 (-2)^(1/3)
            b^2)/(-2 b^3 - 27 d + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[d (4 b^3 + 27 d)])^(
          1/3) + (-2)^(
           2/3) (-2 b^3 - 27 d + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[d (4 b^3 + 27 d)])^(
           1/3))}, {x -> 
       1/6  (-2 b + (
          2 (-1)^(2/3)
            b^2)/(-b^3 + 3/2 (-9 d + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[d (4 b^3 + 27 d)]))^(
          1/3) + (-2 b^3 - 27 d + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[d (4 b^3 + 27 d)])^(1/3)
             Root[-4 + #^3& , 2, 0])}}


where an implicit expression Root[-4 + #^3& , 2, 0] emerges at the end of the third root. I also tried Sol2./{a->1,c->0}//FullSimplifyand the implicit expression is still there.
I was wondering how to get rid of the implicit expression, because I need an explicit solution.
Best,
Charles

P.S. When numerically evaluating the fractional power, i.e., $(-1)^{(1/3)}$, I notice that mathematica gives 0.5 + 0.866025 I, instead of -1. Why is that so? This is confusing.

implicit expression, you mean to get rid of the Root? Try ToRadicals and see if this works on your output. i.e. apply ToRadicals to the solution. https://i.sstatic.net/2fqVakPM.png

It works, thank you @Nasser

Hi, @Nasser. When numerically evaluating fractional power, e.g., $(-1)^{(1/3)}$, mathematica gives 0.5 + 0.866025 I, while I am expecting $-1$. Could you give some hints on this? Thanks in advance~

@Charles6 As to your last question, Mathematica works over the complex numbers, and something like a^(1/n) is assumed to be the symbol representing the $n$'th principal root of $a$, which Mathematica takes to be the one with the smallest non-zero argument (angle with respect to the real axis).

In this case, using Simplify rather than FullSimplify will avoid the Root form of the expression. The Root expression has a lower LeafCount than its corresponding radical expression. x^3 == -1 has three roots. By convention, x^(1/3) is the root with the smallest argument. Look at SortBy[SolveValues[x^3 == -1, x], Arg]// ExpToTrig. The real cube root of -1 is given by Surd[-1, 3]

question fractional power
{-1,1/2 + Sqrt [3]/2 I, 1/2 + Sqrt [3]/2 I}^3 // Simplify
(* {-1,-1,-1}*)

